Base component isn't outputting method passed to the derived component
I have 4 form standalone components that have duplicate html and ts logic (They all have a label and close 'X' button at the top, with 'Close' and 'Submit' buttons at the bottom.
I'm trying to make a base component that the 4 form components can all extend, so I don't need to have all this duplicate code.
Clicking 'Cancel' or 'Submit' doesn't seem to emit and call the method from the parent.
Here is the base component.


import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
@Component({
  selector: 'base-job-form',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './base-job-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./base-job-form.component.scss']
})
export class BaseJobFormComponent {
  @Input() label!: string;
  @Output() onClose: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() onSubmit: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  submit(): void {
    this.onSubmit.emit();
  }

  close(): void {
    this.onClose.emit();
  }
}
<div>
  <div class="primary-header-row mat-subheading-2">
    <div class="inline-block" style="margin-left:2.5em;">{{ label }}</div>
    <button id="close-btn" mat-icon-button matTooltip="Close" (click)="close()"></button>
  </div>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <div class="buttons-container">
    <button accesskey="c" mat-button (click)="close()">Cancel</button>
    <button accesskey="a" mat-button color="primary" (click)="submit()">{{ label }}</button>
  </div>
</div>



Here is one of the derived components.


@Component({
  selector: 'add-group-job-panel',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BaseJobFormComponent
  ],
  templateUrl: './add-group-job-panel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-group-job-panel.component.scss']
})
export class AddGroupJobPanelComponent extends BaseJobFormComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
}
<base-job-form [label]="'Group'">
  <form [formGroup]="addGroupForm" novalidate autocomplete="off">
    <div class="controls-container margin-bottom-up">
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Keys</mat-label>
        <input type="number" matInput formControlName="availablekeys">
      </mat-form-field>
      <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Create</mat-label>
        <input type="number" matInput formControlName="generatekeys>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </form>
</base-job-form>



Here is a parent component that holds the derived component.


import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AddGroupJobPanelComponent } from './add-group-job-panel/add-group-job-panel.component';
@Component({
  selector: 'group',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    AddGroupJobPanelComponent
  ],
  templateUrl: './group.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./group.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class GroupComponent {
  constructor() { }
  submitRequest(): void {
    console.log('group submit');
  }
  closePanel(): void {
    console.log('group close');
  }
}
<add-group-job-panel (onClose)="closePanel()" (onSubmit)="submitRequest()"></add-group-job-panel>



